# How to pass reference parameters in a wcf method and listen to the current value of the parameter in a timer?

Tags: wpf, wcf

I have a wcf method which connects to tfs server and downloads all the files based on the rootpath to the remote machine.

So I have 17K files and it takes 20 minutes to download and I want the progressbar to report the current status after every `for` loop present in the wcf service. But `ref` parameters don't get updated unless the entire method is completed when passed in wcf method.

Is there any other way to do it? I just want to report the status of a current `for` loop iteration happening in wcf method to my `ProgressBar` present in my local wpf application.

Comment: Use `BackgroundWorker`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker

Comment: I already have background worker , and the wcf method is being handled in the do work event , but that method takes 20 minutes to complete , and i am changine a variable there periodically , and i want to get that variable in  my local applicaton. if the method is being called locally , passing parameters as ref will do the trick , but the wcf doesn't update the local app of any change in the ref param passed in its method.

Comment: So you need the `WCF` service to report back to your desktop app some progress status as percents completed?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683171/progress-notification-in-wcf-for-long-running-processes-how or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865537/wcf-informing-about-the-progress-to-client-can-i-use-one-way-call-back-method?